# Postgres FATAL: Error password en pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql

Uso **MacOS Catalina**, y **PostgreSQL 13**

Es un error bastante conocido, pero al que no llego solucionar.
Este es el mensaje:

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

He intentado cambiar el archivo **pg_hba.conf**, y nada.
Desinstalarlo e reinstalando, actualizando y no llego ni siquiera a desbloquear la primera fase de poder utilizar el famoso `ALTER USER ...` . También he actualizado el user en USER&GROUP de Mac y nada.

¿Cómo puede ser esto posible? ^^''

¿Alguien puede recomendar alguna solución o algún enlace?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco el sistema MacOS, pero en Linux la primera contraseña que te pide es la del administrador o root (del sistema Operativo, no de Postgres).

Si no es ese el problema y accedes correctamente al pgAdmin y fallas al intentar abrir un servidor, estaría bien que indicaras que modificaste.

Ya nos cuentas algo. Saludos.